# Is it possible to connect to running NestJS server stderr/stdout?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, stdout, stderr

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I want to connect to existing application to see what logs it produce in realtime. Is it possible to do so from Linux terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `pid` of the process (it should be in the start up logs, or retrieved via a `ps aux | grep <port>` call) you should be able to `tail` it via `tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/2`. [Command found from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session)